# HTML/CSS/JavaScript: How to change color of table row based on data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

First off, I know this may be a duplicate, but I tried the other solutions and nothing was working. Anyhow, I have a table in HTML:

```
<table class="table1">
        <tr>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Picture</th>
            <th>Serial Number</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody class="tbody" >
            <tr class="bodyrow" ng-repeat="item in rank track by $index">
                <td>{{item}}</td>
                <td>{{name[$index]}}</td>
                <td> <img ng-src="{{img[$index]}}"/></td>
                <td>{{serialNumber[$index]}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

So the ranks can be `Basic`, `Middle`, or `Advanced`. If the rank is `Basic` then the entire row of that entry should be blue. If the rank is `Middle`, the row of that entry should be yellow, and `Advanced` should make the row green. Can anybody help, please?

Comment: Look into the documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass Also it would help to show some of the solutions that didn't work.. That way we could point out your problem instead of doing it all for you/

Comment: Couldn't you just put the `{{item}}` in your `tr` class attribute and style according to the class?

Comment: I'm not exclusively looking for an AngularJS solution. It could use pure javascript or jquery as well

Comment: Yep. Wow. Okay, I'm dumb. Thanks!

Comment: @iSuckAtProgramming stick to using the angular solutions where possible, that's why you're using Angular after all.

Comment: @Pogrindis I realized that now, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Markup (assuming the {{item}} have the rank name):

```
<table class="table1">
    <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Picture</th>
        <th>Serial Number</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody class="tbody" >
        <tr class="bodyrow" ng-class="item" ng-repeat="item in rank track by $index">
            <td>{{item}}</td>
            <td>{{name[$index]}}</td>
            <td> <img ng-src="{{img[$index]}}"/></td>
            <td>{{serialNumber[$index]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Styles:

```
.basic{background: blue}
.middle{background: yellow}
.advanced{background: green}
```

Comment: @Quantastical give it a try in Fiddle or something, if it doesn't work, drop it in here. :)